# DKIM and DMARC set up on dedicate 1and1 server

Tags: email, dkim, dmarc

I am having a little trouble figuring out this process. I can manage to get the DNS records set up for the DMARC, DKIM and SPF. I get lost with what i am trying to do with the private key for the DKIM. Currently i am using a dedicated server offered by 1and1.com. if someone can give me a quick walk through i would really appreciate it.

The website i am currently making sends out scheduled emails plus emails on behalf of users. Some of them are being blocked by Hotmail and other email providers. I understand that adding these protocols will increase the likelihood that the emails reach their intended targets. If there are any other mechanisms that can accomplish this as well, i would greatly appreciate a heads up.

i use the built in php mail method to send emails (i do not want to incorporate a third party plugin to do something that php already does and works pretty well)

thanks

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can set DMARC on 1and1. Set:

```
Type:    txt
Prefix:  _dmarc
Value:   v=DMARC1; p=none; sp=none; rua=mailto:yourmail@hotmail.com;     
         ruf=mailto:yourmail@hotmail.com; rf=afrf; pct=100; ri=86400;
```

Change the 2 emails

Comment: Thanks, I did this on 1and1 just now, and it passed the test on http://mxtoolbox.com/domain/mydomainname.com/?source=findmonitors . My settings are Prefix: _dmarc, Value: v=DMARC1; p=reject; rua=mailto:admin@mydomainname.com

Comment: That's good to know they allow it now, send an email to `mailtest@unlocktheinbox.com` and make sure you have no critical issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set up DMARC or DKIM on 1&1 DNS, they don't allow underscores (_) in sub-domains in their DNS records.

Sorry for the bad news. They are the only hosting provider I know about that doesn't allow underscores (unless something changed recently)

DMARC is easy to set up just use this [DMARC Wizard](https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/dmarcwizard/)

DKIM is something that you need to set up with email software program you're using to send mail (which you didn't tell us what you're using) - I'm guessing postfix or exim?

Comment: i actually got all of the DNS settings fine that was the easy part. From there i am totally lost. I am not sure what i am using to send email (the default settings/ 1and1's own emailer) I looked up phpinfo() and it does not mention either exim or postfix. Should i configure one of the two?

Comment: i also should mention i opted for the 1and1 managed dedicated server. im not sure if this will have an affect

Comment: i think i should still be able to adjust the server settings using PuTTY

Comment: What's your domain name so I can check the DNS.

Comment: i removed the DNS settings last night  when i was tinkering but i checked the records on http://mxtoolbox.com/ and it recognized them. I think i only have the SPF record still there

Comment: Yeah, configure either exim on postfix and make sure you select the default option according to this document: [Email with 1&1](https://help.1and1.com/servers-c37684/dedicated-server-linux-c37687/organization-via-control-panel-c37695/e-mail-options-for-1and1-servers-a650143.html). Once you get that set up and your DNS configured, then you can proceed to the next step.  Also if your testing DNS proprogation use this [DNS Tool](https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/dnstools/mx/) it allows you to select different servers to query DNS from.

Comment: I just tried on 1and1, they didn't let me use prefix 'dmarc' but they did allow '_dmarc'. I then checked on mxtoolbox.com, and it said my DMARC was correct.

Comment: Looks like 1&1 now supports underscores in sub-domains now, but they sure don't provide much info beyond that